# Python gives error when trying Serverless deploy

Tags: python, pip, serverless, serverless-framework

I am trying to run a command `serverless deploy`, but I get the following error even though I have a python:

```
Stack xxxxxx failed to deploy (0s)
Environment: win32, node 14.16.1, framework 3.2.1, plugin 6.0.0, SDK 4.3.1
Docs:        docs.serverless.com
Support:     forum.serverless.com
Bugs:        github.com/serverless/serverless/issues

Error:
Error: `python3 -m pip help install` Exited with code 9009
```

my python version is `Python 3.9.6`, my pip version is `pip 21.1.3`

Seems like there is no similar problem on forums.

Comment: Can you also attach the serverless script?